# Angular 6 multiple filtered objects of various sizes

Tags: angular

```
product: Products[] = [];
Cat-Product: Products[] = [];
Type-Product: Products[] = [];
Size-Product: Products[] = [];

private loadMenu() {
   this.pService.getProducts().pipe(first()).subscribe(products => { 
     this.product = product; 
     this.Cat-Product = products.filter(item => item.Category == "Cars"); 
     this.Type-Product = products.filter(item => item.Type == "Ford"); 
     this.Size-Product = `enter code here`products.filter(item => item.Type==="2.0");      
   });
}
```

is this possible in angular?
what more details do you want?

Comment: All I want is to carve up the returned Json object into chunks that I can use in the HTML page.

Comment: What's not working? What do you expect the outcome to be? Your code seems, even though its pseudo, kinda correct. Why don't you first try, and if you run into errors, come back here

Comment: I cant get this working all object in Product are find and I can process these in the HTML but I can even get close to processing Cat,Type and Size json objects I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Can you recreate a simple version on stackblitz, so that we can look into it?

Comment: this.userService.getMenu().pipe(first()).subscribe(menus => { 
            this.menus = menus;    
        });

Comment: I want to process the menus json array and cant, menus is fine in html and <li *ngFor="let menuc of menus" let i=index>  works fine

Comment: Solved with following code:-var tmp = this.MProds.filter(function(v, i) {
                    return ((v['category'] === Cat && v['type'] === type_sel && v['product'] === prod_lbl) );
                  });